# Fullcalendar constraint option not working

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar for a rails application, and I have been trying to figure out how to use the constraint option to limit where events can be moved or created. I have one Event Source (JSON) that I assign with the constraint id ("available") once each event is rendered, and I added the constraint option to the event source I want constrained. When I try to create or move an event in the constrained area, it won't let me. I've used eventClick to verify that the background event does have the expected id for the constraint.

**Appointment.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var title = $('#type').val();
var maker = $('#maker').val();

if (maker == 'seller'){ 
   var sconstraint = "";
   var source = [{ url: '/appointments?appt_type=' + title + '&maker=' + maker, className: 'deletable' }]

} else if (maker == 'buyer') {
   var sconstraint = 'available';
   var source = 
   [{
       url: '/appointments?appt_type=' + title + '&maker=owner',
       editable: false,
       overlap: true,
       rendering: 'background',
       className: 'available'
   },
   {
       url: '/appointments?appt_type=' + title + '&maker=buyer',
       overlap: true,
       editable: true,
       color: 'blue',
       className: "deletable",
       constraint: 'available'
   },
   {
       url: '/appointments?appt_type=' + title + '&maker=others',
       editable: false,
       overlap: false,
       color: 'red'
   }]
}

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  minTime: "8:00:00",
  maxTime: "20:00:00",
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: true,
  unselectAuto: false,
  selectOverlap: true,
  allDaySlot: false,
  editable: true,
  selectConstraint: sconstraint,
  eventSources: source,
  select: function(start, end, allDay) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/appointments",
        data: { appointment: { appt_type: title, start_time: start.format(), end_time: end.format(), maker: maker } },
        success: function(data){
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
            {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                id: data.id,
                className: 'deletable',
                constraint: 'available',
                color: 'blue'

            }, false );
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect'); },
        error: function(xhr){
            var errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors;
        } 
    }); 
  },
    eventResize: function(event){
        $.ajax({
            type: "PATCH",
            url: "/appointments/"+event.id,
            data: { appointment: { end_time: event.end.format()} },
            success: function(data){
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                var errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors;
            } 
        });       
    },
    eventDrop: function(event){
        $.ajax({
            type: "PATCH",
            url: "/appointments/"+event.id,
            data: { appointment: { start_time: event.start.format(), end_time: event.end.format()} },
            success: function(data){
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                var errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors;
            } 
        });       
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        if(element.hasClass('available')){
          event.id = 'available';
        }
        if (element.hasClass('deletable')) {
          element.find('.fc-time').append("<span class='closeon pull-right'>X</span>"); 
        }
        element.find(".closeon").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "/appointments/"+event.id,
                data: { appointment: { appt_type: event.title, start_time: event.start.format(), end_time: event.end.format()} },
                success: function(data){
                },
                error: function(xhr){
                    var errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors;
                } 
            });
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
        });
    },
    eventClick: function(event) {
      console.log(event.id);
    }


});


});
```

Comment: I'm unable to find a reference to constraint 'available' what does this do?

Comment: 'available' is an event ID for all the events from the first event source. According to the Fullcalendar documentation, you should be able to use event IDs as the constraint.

Comment: You appear to be using 'available' as teh className not the EventID?  Would this make a difference

Comment: @TobyAllen under the EventRender option I assign all the events with that class name with the id "available", and my eventClick alert confirms the id assignment was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to use the eventDataTransform option to convert the incoming id from the event source to the id of the constraint.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!